# How to have a bunch of instances of a prototype?

Tags: javascript

[Fiddle!!](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/K8cha/2/)

I am trying to set up a system where I can have a bunch of instances of `colorBox`, I have one here named `box`. Everything is working fine, except I want to be able to alter the styles of my new colorBox(s) after they have been created doing something like `box.resetColor('blue');` To test this, I have created a simple function `vodoo` which just alerts you. But I cant call `box.vodoo()` because colorBox is a function not an object.

What is the best way to have a bunch of instances of `colorbox` that can be updated individually whenever you want without having to update all the properties of the `box` (only the ones you want)?

JS:

```
var colorBox = function(node, options) {
    this.setSize = function(){
        node.style.width = options.width + 'px';
        node.style.height = options.height + 'px';
    };
    this.setColor = function(){
        node.style.backgroundColor = options.color;
    };
    this.setSize();
    this.setColor();
    vodoo(){
        alert('vodoo');
    }
}

var node = document.getElementById('thing1');
var options = {
    color: 'red',
    width: 200,
    height: 200
}

var box = new colorBox(node, options);
box.vodoo();
```

Comment: You have an syntax error in your code if you want to declare function, you should to do so... function vodoo() { alert('vodoo'); }

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: `"because colorBox is a function not an object."` in javascript functions are objects of Function data type.

Comment: You can create as many objects as you wish, of your colorBox (custom data type). and they all will have own copy of properties and methods.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/K8cha/7/ maybe you want something like this?

Comment: @Givi you seem to be repeating your code more than in MaxPRafferty's answer. I think it is better to define the funcs and then invoke them rather than what you did... but i dunno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/K8cha/5/

I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to do here, but there is a syntax error in the way you have declared voodoo. This change causes this to work:

```
var colorBox = function(node, options) {
    this.setSize = function(){
        node.style.width = options.width + 'px';
        node.style.height = options.height + 'px';
    };
    this.setColor = function(){
        node.style.backgroundColor = options.color;
    };
    this.setSize();
    this.setColor();
    this.voodoo = function(){
        alert('voodoo');
    }
}
```

Additionally, in JS the Function object is a descendant of the Object object, and so can be used as such with its own properties, etc.